# Monitor changes on database with AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i am making a kind of monitor, that shows the changes on database that are created by another web application, i was reloading the page every 10 seconds to show the changes but, i think that is not the "way" to do it, so i was made some research and i found that ajax can do that, calling a function that check that changes, so i wrote my code, but something is missing, so am calling the experts, tha main idea is that when the page are loaded take the id(number) of that last row that was inserted and then saved in a variable called $resultado then call a function called check_changes that do the same query and check the results, if the both variable are equal then no changes, if they are different the reload page.

monitor.php

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <?
    //code that makes and print the query.

    // here i check the last id(number) and saved on $resultado variable
    $qry0="SELECT emergencia.id FROM emergencia ORDER BY emergencia.id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $qry1=db_query($qry0,$conn);
    while($row=$qry1->fetch_array()) 
    { 
    $resultado=$row['id'];
    }

    //here i call check_changes every 30 seconds
    echo "<script>setTimeout('check_changes()',30);"; 
    //ajax function that check the status of database
    echo "function check_changes(){
    $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: {'data':$resultado}, //here am sending the value of result via post
url: './checker.php',   //to checker.php
success: function(data) {
if(data.result==true){ 
window.location = window.location.pathname;
} 
}
})
    }";
    echo "</script>";
    ?>
```

checker.php

```
    <?
    $result4 = $_POST['data'];
    include( "/home/ocelas/proyecto/include/inter_dbc_innodb.php" );
    $dbc=connect_db("seguridad");

    // here i check the last id(number) and saved on $result3 variable
    $qry0="SELECT emergencia.id FROM emergencia ORDER BY emergencia.id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $qry1=$dbc->query($qry0);
    while($row=$qry1->fetch_array()) 
    {  
    $result3=$row['id'];
    }

    //here i check if both are equal send false to monitor.php
    if ($result4==$result3){
    $result=false
    echo json_encode($result); 
    }
    else {
    // a new row has been inserted, send true to monitor.php an reload page
    $result=true
    echo json_encode($result); 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pollTimeout;
var observeChange = {
          'poll' : function() {
              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'checker.php',
                   data:"data=<?php echo $resultado; ?>",
                   dataType:"json",
                   async:true,
                   success:function(response){
                        // we have success fully received response,clear the timeout
                       clearTimeout(pollTimeout);                                          
                       observeChange.update(response);                             
                   },
                   error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
                        //some error has occured please try after 5 seconds
                        pollTimeout = setTimeout(function()
                        {
                            observeChange.poll();
                        }, 1000);

                    }
                });

          },
          'update' : function(json) {
              //check whether change is there from serever or not if yes than reload page else do poll request again
              if(json.changed=="yes"){
                        window.location.reload();
              }
              else{
                observeChange.poll();
               }
          }
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
      observeChange.poll();           
    });
    </script>
```

you can easily do it via comet,it is not advisable to query server for every 10 seconds,you should increase timeout on apache server if you are using apache

suggested apache configurations are

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 240
MaxClients 150
MaxRequestsPerChild 4
```

checker.php

```
<?
$result4 = $_POST['data'];
$response=array("changed"=>"no");
include( "/home/ocelas/proyecto/include/inter_dbc_innodb.php" );
$dbc=connect_db("seguridad");

// here i check the last id(number) and saved on $result3 variable
$qry0="SELECT emergencia.id FROM emergencia ORDER BY emergencia.id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
$qry1=$dbc->query($qry0);
while($row=$qry1->fetch_array()) 
{  
$result3=$row['id'];
}

if ($result4==$result3){
   $response['changed']="yes"; 
}
echo json_encode($response); exit;
?>
```

Comment: the code above its on comet? o i can test with prototype or jquery?, i am not a web programer, am working on construction, this is only for remember how to really use a computer, so sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: you can test it with jquery

Comment: you need to consider apache configurations only if you want to increase server overhead by increasing request wait time to 2-4 mins rather than 10 seconds,otherwise it is fine.

Comment: tried this echo "<script>setTimeout('observeChange()',100)</script>;"      echo "info above"; replacing " with ' on code, and if(json.changed=="yes") with if(json.changed=='true'), but not working, please help, i have at least 2 weeks i cant figure out how to making work.

Comment: replace your javascript code with mine(i have changed it),please dont forget to include jquery min js file,observe newly added code for checker.php

Comment: do your browser sends requests at regular interval,do you recieve response or not?

Comment: not send nothing, static at all, but reading your code in checker.php if $result4==$result3 your sending yes, but its wrong.. if both are equal then no changes in database so need send no, right?

Comment: yep,sorry for that if ($result4!=$result3){
   $response['changed']="yes"; 
}

Comment: you can debug javascript using firebug addon for firefox to find out what is wrong with js and why it is not sending ajax request to server,it may be because of some missing semicolon,or syntax error.

Comment: i made the change ($result4!=$result3){ $response['changed']="yes"; }, and when i loaded the page starts reloading alone every 1 second

Comment: so i think checker.php is not receiving the variable, so when checker.php is procesed the value of $result4 are null, so makes the check, null are different from $result3 so reload the page every second, your sending with GET an receiving with POST its that ok?

Comment: so now js has started working now you need to do changes in checker.php such that it sends yes/no as per your requirement and it will work fine

Comment: i already made the changes, and checker.php is not receiving the value sended on ajax to checker.php so $result4 is always null, so $result4 is always different from $result3 so starts reloading the page always.

Comment: ok got it in  $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: 'checker.php', chage type from "GET" to "POST"

Comment: nope check your self ocelas-server.servehttp.com/proyecto/Pruebas/      user gcabrera pass gcabrera ang go to monitor

Comment: getting 60{"changed":"yes"} initially and than {"changed":"no"},looks like started working

Comment: check again, id added values in checker.php, sorry. returning to your code

Comment: put your query code before my javascript <?
    //code that makes and print the query.

    // here i check the last id(number) and saved on $resultado variable
    $qry0="SELECT emergencia.id FROM emergencia ORDER BY emergencia.id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $qry1=db_query($qry0,$conn);
    while($row=$qry1->fetch_array()) 
    { 
    $resultado=$row['id'];
    }

Comment: man... am crying!!!! really dude!!!! you are the man, give me your name to put to my first son, thank you so much

Comment: if you look at the page source than there is no field value with data you can manually set 60(or wahtever you like it) statically and test it in js ajax request where i have written <?php echo $resultado; ?>

Comment: am checking that is i open de monitor.php its sending data to checker.php that shocks de internet connectio, how can i modified this to wait 10 seconds on every check?

Comment: i resolved i add setTimeout(function(){observeChange.poll();},5000);

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some semicolons in your php-code. I don't think it works at all. You should check for php error messages generated in your postback script.

In your javascript you are comparing the result to a boolean value. The data returned will be a string. This is the correct way, notice the single quotes.

```
if(data.result=='true'){ 
window.location = window.location.pathname;
}
```

Comment: not working, the page dont reload after new row inserted, thanks

Comment: Then you have to debug. What is the response you retreive from the ajax call? Does the script return any php errors? Why are you using a incomplete <script> tag?

Comment: no errors on debug, run fine, but not reloading. still checking and testing XD

Answer (score 0):

in **checker.php** you are **sending data after converting into JSON format** ,
but **in ajax request** you **haven't defined the datatype** at all,
also if the data coming at ajax success is JSON then you have to parse it first..

```
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: 'checker.php',
               data:{'ata:$resultado},
               dataType:"json",
               success:function(data){
                       if( JSON.parseQuery(data)) //this will run if the result is true.
                         {
                          window.location = window.location.pathname;
                         }            
               }
           });
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, do i have to convert to json format?? the idea is sending a value $resultado=(number) to check on checker.php with another (number) an retrieve in json format true or false to do the reload, thanks for your time

Comment: it is not necessary to convert your data sending through ajax request, into json format,but as json string is smaller and faster hence ,it is better to use it.

Comment: am testing your code, but if the result of checker.php its true, how your code recognize that "result" and do the refresh?, could you please finish de code? i am really desperate. thanks

Comment: this is over client side, server side code is urs only where u r comparing with send array, the data which came is - what ever it is echoed at server side, so u echoed json format of $result(true/false) ,here after parsing result(i.e. data) you would get true/false.