# configure index.php to monitor sql database and reload self

Tags: java, php, mysql

I'm looking to use java inside my index.php file to monitor changes in a sql database. The database will be updated  by a button press detected through GPIO and python where the new entry and i+1 for every button press. I'd like to have this information updated on a display screen after each button press.

All parts are in place except having my index.php which is displayed on screen update after the button press. I have tried this using xdotool with absolutely no luck. Hours spent using this and it seems that  chromium kiosk mode just doesn't work because I can get the reload sent if just using terminal.

I have zero experience writing java but can understand the syntax fairly well. What sort of script do I need to add to index.php which will monitor the database "update" every ~10s for a new entry line? Simplicity will be good. Appreciate any feedback the community can provide.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078784/monitor-changes-on-database-with-ajax-php

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what I'm after. I don't know how I missed it in my hours of searching and trying without luck. Thanks Kenneth! Hopefully I can adapt it into my own version without issue.